# wxWidgets ScrolledPanel tab order doesn't work

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I had a page that was working fine with respect to tab order, but since I added a scrolled panel to the page, you can only tab between the first control in the ScrolledPanel and the navigation buttons outside the ScrolledPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I need to set wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL as a style on the ScrolledWindow.  Apparently it's not set by default.

Comment: `wxScrolledWindow` does have `wxTAB_TRAVERSAL` by default, not sure why would it be different in Python...